# Do NDAs limit disclosure of their own terms

Tags: united-states, non-disclosure

I have always been interested in putting up a website where people upload NDAs.  They would be properly redacted if applicable and reviewed.

I have worked in software for a long time, in many positions, and the variety of NDA silliness is out of this world.  I have always wanted to get these in the public domain, ideally associated with the parent company, to provide a forum for discussion on NDA abuse.

The succinct question is "Can this be done legally?".

I see an NDA as a pseudo-public document, something you need to read in detail before you acknowledge and opt-in to limit rights (discussion of topic/tech).

Mainly interested in USA.

Comment: Laws on NDAs vary by jurisdiction (Country, and state or province in a Federal country such as Canada, the US, or India). You might get a better answer if you specify a jurisdiction of interest

Comment: "*Can this be done legally?*" Short answer: Generally speaking, yes, it is lawful to do that. The main exceptions are (1) a contractual prohibition that only affects the party(-ies), and (2) where the information is so sensitive that no reasonable person would disclose it to the public. The latter exception is more of a tort than a statutory or contractual violation. Where's the website? I have some material I can contribute and of which unlawful provisions can be highlighted.

Comment: @IñakiViggers the "contractual prohibition" is interesting. Logically it fails, I can not be contractually limited only by reading a contract that I do not need to sign.  A non-sequitur type of issue.

Comment: @Marc "*I can not be contractually limited only by reading a contract that I do not need to sign*". Right, a contract or agreement does not constrain non-parties. But I was referring to the parties to the agreement, that is, the persons who actually signed an agreement that prohibits them to disclose the terms (as it often happens with settlements to avoid trial).

Comment: @IñakiViggers We are on the same page, sorry if we got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It doesn’t matter

An NDA is protected by copyright, just like any other literary work. It is unlikely that the person who uploads it is the owner of that copyright. As such, uploading it is copyright violation and the website owner will spend all their time dealing with DMCA take down notices.

Arguably, posting it is fair use for criticism and commentary, however, that’s an argument for the poster to make. As the website, you will need to take it down unless and until the poster responds. This is likely to make your website frustrating and ultimately worthless.

Comment: Okay, that seems solid. I am looking for a concrete citation on that.  I do believe you are correct b/c the issuing entity will have paid a lawyer to write it.  More commonly NDAs are "tweaked" from something online, those would be a hard fight.  If you pay a lawyer or bought a template you should own the final product and that is copyright-able.  Since most NDA is of dubious origin (tweaked or stolen) that is considerably fuzzier...lacking an audit trail.  Section 230 would protect me, but you are correct - in the instance of legitimate "ownership" DMCA takedown would apply.

Comment: @Marc "*Okay, that seems solid.*" But it's not. Even if the NDA meets the criteria of innovation and creativity, the [Copyright Act at §107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107) authorizes reproduction on grounds of *fair use*, which includes "*purposes such as criticism, [and] comment*". Your intent is not to plagiarize, but "*to provide a forum for discussion on NDA abuse*", aka criticism. "*the issuing entity will have paid a lawyer to write it*", and that is for purposes that have little or nothing to do with the innovation and creativity that the Copyright Act seeks to protect.

Comment: -1 Many NDA texts are largely copied from previous NDAs written by someone else, and so will have little or no copyright protection. Beyond that, posting an NDA text in order to comment on or criticize the NDA is highly likely to constitute **Fair use**  under 17 USC 107. There is no economic loss to the copyright holder, there is no significant market for the NDA text, and the use is transformative. I will add a fuller analysis to my answer, but this isn't close to a definitive answer to the issue. [...]

Comment: [...] The site operator can quite probably simply ignore any takedown notices, or provide counter notices if the takedowns are directed to the upstream service provider.. The takedowens could also be published as the "Chilling Effects" site does. In the UK such a posting would probably fall under "Fair dealing". Attn @Marc

Comment: @DavidSiegel That is very interesting.  Taking it a step further, every NDA could be wrapped with a "history" that would remain.  Possibly a comments section that ostensibly could remain after a takedown.  Legally addressing any valid takedowns in a manner to stay compliant will add to the "history", and any shareable documents related to the takedown can also be posted.  That really strikes the core of this idea - don't be a sh!thead (companies).  I love watchdog enterprises and the various canary paradigms (such as those used for pen letters) - so this is totally cool stuff.

Comment: No law compels a website operator to honor a takedown notice. The worst that happens is the operator loses safe harbor status. See 17 USC 512 (c)(1)(C). Many site operators are not willing to forfeit safe harbor status. Or a site could honor takedowns, and also honor counter notices, informing users how to submit counter-notices. (see 512 (e)(1)) This retains safe harbor status.

Answer (score 3):

The question reads:

> I see an NDA as a pseudo-public document, something you need to read in detail before you acknowledge and opt-in to limit rights (discussion of topic/tech).

Unfortunately for this view, the law normally sees an NDA as a private contract, except when it is alleged that it violates public policy. If an NDA explicitly or implicitly includes itself in the list of things not to be disclosed, then posting it would be a violation of the contract. In such a case  the party posting the agreement would be subject to whatever consequence the agreement specifies for violation, unless that person had a valid defense. The operator of a web site where the document might be posted would not normally ne a party to the agreement, and so would not be liable for hosting it, unless some other limitation applies, beyond the NDA itself.

An NDA can indeed be a significant limitation on the signer's freedom to discuss certain topics, and a person would be wise to consider it in detail, and perhaps consult a lawyer, before signing one. But that does not mean that the person should post or distribute it publicly, nor that the person is automatically entitled to consult NDAs that others have signed. There are sufficient sample NDA forms available that a person can compare an offered NDA with other possibilities, and get an idea if an offered NDA goes beyond the usual terms.

Comment: "*nor that the person is automatically entitled to consult NDAs that others have signed.*" I doubt the OP thought in terms of *entitlement* over others. Based on his description, it seems safe to assume that he would *invite* the public to share and discuss outrageous NDAs.

Comment: I once had to sign and NDA in order to look at the NDA that covered the substance of the scope. Little company had a secret agreement with Big Company and I was thinking of working for Little Company. Everyone in the industry knew they had a big contract but not with whom. I had to sign a Little Company NDA (1) that said I would be shown an NDA(2) with an unnamed big company and whether or not I signed the second NDA I needed to not disclose the name of the big company. Upon signing the second NDA I could get more details of the project.

Comment: "explicitly or implicitly includes itself in the list of things not to be disclosed" NEVER seen that EVER. I have had to rewrite NDAs more than once.  I suppose safe passage and current (today) section 230 will be on my side generally speaking.  But Oracle, for example, would not be very pleased.  The #1 desire is to track these often dubious documents and provide a baseline fear for companies to keep it realistic. @IñakiViggers correct, public interest.

Comment: I always wondered if that existed @GeorgeWhite - thanks for confirming in the wild and the double NDA makes sense for the really paranoid.  Would not post the second, but the first would be "game".  That little company NDA would be very telling I suppose, at least to those who know more...

Comment: It was 25 years ago (both NDA terms expired) and Big Company was AT&T who has not been in the computer industry for most of those years.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the contractual prohibition is this: "We offer you X, and you must agree to terms Y, one part of which is not disclosing Q" (Q could be anything, including the content of that offer"). If you accept the offer, you are bound by it, and if Q includes "cannot disclose the content of this contract", you cannot both accept the contract and disclose the contract. You can reject the contract, in which case you are not bound by the NDA (also, you don't get whatever benefit comes from their offer). For instance, Jones clobbers your car and causes you $50,000 in damage. Rather than litigate, they offer you $51,000 with the proviso that you not reveal the terms of the agreement (the NDA is a part of the settlement offer). You can accept the offer in which case you are bound by the NDA, or you can reject the offer meaning that you don't get the money, and you are free to disclose the offer. It is incumbent on the offeror to devise a method to prevent you from rejecting and disclosing: for example a shorter agreement that they will make a putatively beneficient offer to you, provided that you don't disclose the content of the offer (even if you reject the offer). You cannot be bound to a contract simply by reading it.

This ignores the class of non-contractual NDAs like doctor-patient or attorney-patient confidentiality which might be governed by specific statutory conditions.

Comment: Solved by a pair of nested NDAs. I had the experience of signing an NDA that covered to terms of a second NDA that I was shown only after signing the first one. Didn’t need to sign second one but couldn’t disclose its terms - including the  identify of the party the second NDA was with.